# Inter-laboratory results comparison

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Having sampled nitrogen at several points on the fields, we sent the samples to three different institutes. The results for the same point should be comparable but it seems that the values measured by Institutes 1, 2, and 3 are not highly correlated.

I have checked the literature and found several papers where it has been stated that for inter-laboratory results, the Z-score should be less than 2:
The z-score measures the deviation of the result of each laboratory from the “true” value, by comparison with a reference standard deviation. The interpretation for the z-score is the following:

- |Z| ≤ 2 Gratifying results
- 2 <|Z| ≤ 3 Questionable results
- |Z| ≥ 3 Degratifying results

Calculating Z score based just on 3 values (for every point), the results, I believe, have not much significance.

Here are the example measurements:

```
        sample_id                 Institute 1 NO3-N Institute 2 NO3-N Institute 3 NO3-N

0       MU-53-1 (T1)               8.26             19.72             12.66
1       MU-53-1 (T2)               8.20             13.26              14.9
2       MU-53-1 (T3)               5.10             12.96             17.98
3       MU-53-1 (T4)               5.15             11.48             12.86
4       MU-53-1 (T5)               4.17             10.19             13.03
5   MU-53-1 composite              3.33              6.96              5.92
6   MU-53-1 composite              1.32              4.53              4.59
7       MU-53-2 (T6)               6.36             12.04             12.58
8       MU-53-2 (T7)               6.18                10              9.11
9       MU-53-2 (T8)               2.88             11.32             16.22
10      MU-53-2 (T9)               3.93             10.67             10.35
11     MU-53-2 (T10)               4.92              10.3             13.26
12  MU-53-2 composite              2.15              6.26              9.32
13  MU-53-2 composite              1.73              4.95              4.42
```

Does anyone know if there is any other way to evaluate the results in order to determine if the results from different laboratories are reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is not an appropriate metric for checking measurement agreement. The measurements [1, 1.5, 2] and [2, 2.5, 3] are perfectly correlated yet in poor agreement.

Instead you can use inter-observer variability to quantify the disagreement between measurements taken at each pair of laboratories.

```
#>      instrument1        instrument2   inter-variability
#>      Laboratory2        Laboratory1               5.28
#>      Laboratory3        Laboratory1               6.07
#>      Laboratory3        Laboratory2               2.34
```

Inter-observer disagreement doesn't determine whether the laboratories are reliable or not. Laboratories 2 and 3 agree more with each other than with Laboratory 1 but it might be the case that they are both biased in the same direction and Laboratory 1 is more precise than either.

To answer the question which laboratory takes the most accurate measurements you have to compare their measurements to measurements taken with a "gold standard" equipment/procedure.

*Notes*

- Intra- and inter-measurement variability is discussed in a lot more detail in Chapter 16 of *Biostatistics for Biomedical Research* course notes. Available [online](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/).
- You can find R code to compute intra- and inter-observer disagreement [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/578404/237901).