# Appropriate statistical model to evaluate the quality of measurements from different instruments?

Tags: confirmatory-factor, calibration, lavaan

I have a dataset where a number of samples (>600) were weighed by three different instruments, called V G and P. Each instrument was used three times to weigh each sample so there are nine values total per sample. One of the instruments (V) is considered a "standard," so the comparisons of interest are really between the other two instruments, G and P.

This is what the data look like (each sample is identified by a unique combination of the identifiers `Trial`, `Year`, and `Plot`). As you can see there is variability between samples, between instruments within a sample, and often within instruments within a single sample as well.

```
     Trial Year Plot   G1   G2   G3   P1   P2   P3   V1   V2   V3
  1:    H6 2020  101 55.8 55.8 55.8 56.3 56.1 56.9 56.3 56.0 56.2
  2:    H6 2020  102 56.3 56.3 56.3 57.2 57.4 57.2 56.3 56.5 56.6
  3:    H6 2020  103 55.7 55.7 55.7 58.0 57.8 57.9 57.7 57.3 57.0
  4:    H6 2020  104 57.5 57.5 57.5 57.9 58.5 58.8 57.1 57.6 57.6
  5:    H6 2020  107 58.3 58.2 58.2 57.9 57.1 57.2 56.2 56.5 56.6
 ---                                                             
642:    U8 2020  311 57.4 57.4 57.4 57.3 57.0 57.3 56.8 56.2 56.2
643:    U8 2020  312 57.6 57.6 57.6 57.5 57.0 57.5 56.4 56.6 56.3
644:    U8 2020  313 54.9 54.9 54.9 55.7 55.3 55.6 54.9 54.2 54.8
645:    U8 2020  314 57.1 57.0 57.0 56.3 56.1 56.1 55.0 54.9 54.9
646:    U8 2020  315 54.4 54.4 54.4 55.5 55.6 55.6 54.7 54.5 54.4
```

I have two goals:

- To assess the relative quality of G and P. For example do either of them have a systematic bias or does one produce more variable measurements than the other on the same sample?
- To create a calibration equation relating each of the readings from G and P to the standard V, so that we can in the future correct readings from them.

I thought the best way to do this would be with a latent variable confirmatory factor analysis model where we assume there is an unobserved true value for each sample, and we observe 9 different values each time. This is how I set up the model in lavaan in R:

```
cfa_model <- 
  'W_true =~ V + G + P
   V =~ V1 + V2 + V3
   G =~ G1 + G2 + G3
   P =~ P1 + P2 + P3'
```

There are four latent variables, the "true" weight `W_true`, and a variable for each of the three instruments.

I fit the model like this:

```
cfa(model = cfa_model, data = mydata)
```

This is what the model DAG looks like:

[image]

After fitting the model I tried to get a prediction for the latent variables but they are given as factor scores and I am not sure how to convert those back to the same scale as the data (i.e. I would expect the unobserved true weight to be around 56 for the first row). So I'm not sure how to use this to get a calibration equation to use later. I am concerned that I am thinking about this wrong and this is the wrong way to be doing this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate bias as the difference between the mean or median weight measurements. Variability is more challenging as it has two components:

- Intra-variability quantifies the *repeatability* of measurements taken with the same instrument.
- Inter-variability quantifies the *disagreement* between measurements taken with two different instruments.

---

**NB** Intra- and inter-measurement variability is discussed in a lot more detail in Chapter 16 of *Biostatistics for Biomedical Research* course notes. Available [online](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/).

---

First let's look at the weight measurements for the 10 samples you've provided.

[image]

We learn a lot from this plot. The two most interesting observations are: instrument G has almost no intra-variability and instrument P is consistently over-biased.

Let's put these observations into numbers. I'll use the procedure described in BBR. The R code is attached at the end.

First we consider intra-variability. The standard instrument, V, measures the weight of sample 1 as [56.3, 56, 56.2]. We pair the measurements and compute the absolute differences: |56.3 - 56| = .3, |56.3 - 56.2| = .1, |56 - 56.2| = .2. The average (.3 + .1 + .2) / 3 = .2 is a measure of variability known as Gini's mean difference.

Below I've plotted the intra-instrument variability for each sample. Take the average across samples to estimate the overall intra-varibility.

[image]

```
#>   instrument    intra-variability
#>            G               0.0133
#>            P               0.293
#>            V               0.280
```

Second we consider inter-variability. The standard instrument, V, measures the weight of sample 1 as [56.3, 56, 56.2] while the alternative instrument, P, measure its weight as [56.3, 56.1, 56.9]. We pair each V measurement with each P measurement and compute the absolute differences: 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7. The average 0.33 is measure of the disagreement between V and P about the weight of sample 1.

Below I've plotted the inter-instrument variability between V and either P or G, for each sample. Again, take the average across samples to estimate the overall inter-variability.

[image]

```
#>   instrument1 instrument2     inter-variability
#>             V           P                 0.85
#>             V           G                 0.883
#>             P           G                 0.867
```

And finally let's estimate weight as the median measurement by an instrument.

[image]

```
#> bias   G - V   P - V
#>         0.39   0.830
```

The computations confirm and elaborate on the observations we made at the start by plotting the raw measurements:

- Instrument G has little intra-variability (0.013) while instruments V and P have about the same intra-variability (0.28 and 0.29 respectively).
- Instrument G has less bias than instrument P (0.39 and 0.83 respectively).
- Instrument G has slightly higher inter-disagreement with instrument V (0.88) than instrument P (0.85).
- On the given 10 samples, instrument P is consistently over-biased while instrument G has two "modes": it has low bias for samples 1,2,4,8,10 and high bias for samples 3,5,6,7,9.

R code in all its gory details.

```
data <- data.frame(
  Trial = c("H6", "H6", "H6", "H6", "H6", "U8", "U8", "U8", "U8", "U8"),
  Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L),
  Plot = c(101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 107L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L),
  G1 = c(55.8, 56.3, 55.7, 57.5, 58.3, 57.4, 57.6, 54.9, 57.1, 54.4),
  G2 = c(55.8, 56.3, 55.7, 57.5, 58.2, 57.4, 57.6, 54.9, 57, 54.4),
  G3 = c(55.8, 56.3, 55.7, 57.5, 58.2, 57.4, 57.6, 54.9, 57, 54.4),
  P1 = c(56.3, 57.2, 58, 57.9, 57.9, 57.3, 57.5, 55.7, 56.3, 55.5),
  P2 = c(56.1, 57.4, 57.8, 58.5, 57.1, 57, 57, 55.3, 56.1, 55.6),
  P3 = c(56.9, 57.2, 57.9, 58.8, 57.2, 57.3, 57.5, 55.6, 56.1, 55.6),
  V1 = c(56.3, 56.3, 57.7, 57.1, 56.2, 56.8, 56.4, 54.9, 55, 54.7),
  V2 = c(56, 56.5, 57.3, 57.6, 56.5, 56.2, 56.6, 54.2, 54.9, 54.5),
  V3 = c(56.2, 56.6, 57, 57.6, 56.6, 56.2, 56.3, 54.8, 54.9, 54.4)
)

library("tidyverse")
iccmlr::theme_set_amazon()

GiniSd <- function(x, y = NULL, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if (is.null(y)) {
    # Adapted from Hmisc::GiniMd
    if (na.rm) {
      k <- is.na(x)
      if (any(k)) {
        x <- x[!k]
      }
    }
    n <- length(x)
    if (n < 2) {
      return(NA)
    }
    w <- 2 * ((1:n) - (n - 1) / 2)
    sum(w * sort(x - mean(x)))
  } else {
    sum(outer(x, y, function(xi, yi) abs(xi - yi)))
  }
}

Aggregate <- function(variabilities, ...) {
  variabilities %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarise(
      variability = sum(N * variability) / sum(N),
      N = sum(N)
    )
}

Estimate <- function(sample, instrument, measurement) {
  measurements <- tibble(
    sample,
    instrument,
    measurement
  )
  measurements %>%
    group_by(
      sample,
      instrument
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      measurement = median(measurement)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = sample,
      names_from = instrument,
      values_from = measurement
    )
}

IntraVariability <- function(sample, instrument, measurement) {
  measurements <- tibble(
    sample,
    instrument,
    measurement
  )
  intra_var <- measurements %>%
    group_by(
      sample,
      instrument
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      N = choose(n(), 2),
      variability = GiniSd(measurement) / N
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    drop_na()
  list(
    intra_var = intra_var,
    by_sample = Aggregate(intra_var, sample),
    by_instrument = Aggregate(intra_var, instrument)
  )
}

InterVariability <- function(sample, instrument, measurement) {
  measurements <- tibble(
    sample,
    instrument,
    measurement
  )
  
  nested <- measurements %>%
    chop(measurement)
  
  inter_var <-
    inner_join(
      nested %>% rename(instrument1 = instrument, x = measurement),
      nested %>% rename(instrument2 = instrument, y = measurement),
      by = "sample"
    ) %>%
    filter(
      instrument1 > instrument2
    ) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
      N = length(x) * length(y),
      variability = GiniSd(x, y) / N
    ) %>%
    select(
      -c(x, y)
    ) %>%
    drop_na()
  list(
    inter_var = inter_var,
    by_sample = Aggregate(inter_var, sample),
    by_instrument_pairs = Aggregate(inter_var, instrument1, instrument2)
  )
}

plot_measurements <- function(measurements, measurement) {
  measurements %>%
    arrange(
      sample, instrument, {{ measurement }}
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      id = cumsum(sample != lag(sample, default = ""))
    ) %>%
    group_by(
      sample, instrument
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      h = cumsum({{ measurement }} == lag({{ measurement }}, default = 0)),
      y = id + 0.1 * h
    ) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes({{ measurement }}, y,
          shape = instrument,
          color = instrument
      )
    ) +
    geom_hline(
      aes(yintercept = y),
      linetype = 3,
      color = "gray",
      size = 0.5,
      data = tibble(y = seq(1, 10, 1))
    ) +
    geom_point(
      stroke = 1,
      size = 2
    ) +
    scale_shape_manual(
      values = c(0, 1, 2)
    ) +
    theme(
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    )
}

measurements <- data %>%
  unite(
    "sample", c(Trial, Year, Plot)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -sample,
    names_to = "instrument",
    names_transform = list(instrument = ~ str_sub(., 1, 1))
  )

estimates <- Estimate(
  measurements$sample,
  measurements$instrument,
  measurements$value
)
estimates %>%
  summarise(
    `G - V` = mean(G - V),
    `P - V` = mean(P - V)
  )

intra_var <- IntraVariability(
  measurements$sample,
  measurements$instrument,
  measurements$value
)
intra_var$by_instrument

inter_var <- InterVariability(
  measurements$sample,
  measurements$instrument,
  measurements$value
)
inter_var$by_instrument_pairs

# Make scatterplots

p <- plot_measurements(measurements, value)
p + ggtitle("Raw measurements")

p <- plot_measurements(
  estimates %>% pivot_longer(c(G, P, V), names_to = "instrument", values_to = "estimate"),
  estimate
)
p + ggtitle("Estimated weight")

p <- plot_measurements(intra_var$intra_var, variability)
p + ggtitle("Intra variability")

p <- plot_measurements(
  inter_var$inter_var %>% filter(instrument1 == "V") %>% rename(instrument = instrument2),
  variability
)
p + ggtitle("Inter variability (V - ?)")
```

Comment: I wanted to follow up and say that this was a very valuable and helpful post. I thanked you in the acknowledgments section of a MS we are submitting partly based on this.

Comment: @qdread This is kind. Thanks for the acknowledgement and letting me know about it.